# Composition of a covering and a continuous function

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, covering-spaces

Let $X, E_1, E_2$ be path-connected topological spaces with coverings $f_1:E_1 \to X$ and $f_2:E_2 \to X$ where we have additionally a continuous function $\phi:E_1 \to E_2$ such that the composition of $f_2$ and $\phi$ is equal to $f_1$. Show that $\phi$ is also a covering.

First we note that $\phi$ is surjective since we can lift paths from $X$ to $E_1$ and $E_2$ respectively and they are unique, and by using in addition the equality $f_1 = f_2 \circ \phi$, the surjectivity follows. But how to continue from here? Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does a morphism between covering spaces define a covering?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/109695/does-a-morphism-between-covering-spaces-define-a-covering)

Comment: @HallaSurvivor Sadly no, since we have different assumptions, if we were to assume that $X$ is locally path-connected, then I can see how the statement follows, but in our case we don't have that assumption.

Comment: What is the sourec of your question? An exercise in a textbook?

Comment: @PaulFrost its from an old test problem

Comment: This answers your question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1573115/the-universal-cover-of-a-path-connected-locally-path-connected-space-x-covers

Comment: Perhaps Ronnie Brown's answer to https://math.stackexchange.com/q/109695 will help. But I doubt that it is true without any "local niceness" assumptions.